# Tudo bem armazenar a senha em uma variável pública da classe?

Tags: php, autenticação, hash

Estou fazendo um pequeno sistema de login em PHP usando as novas funções de `password_hash` e `password_verify`. É uma boa prática armazenar a senha em uma variável public da classe? Se não for, é recomendado que se utilize alguma outra encriptação rápida como md5 só para não deixar a senha armazenada?

Um exemplo:

```
function User($name,$pass){
    $this->username = $name;
    $this->password = md5($pass); //Armazenar em md5 para nao armazenar a senha sem encriptação.
}
```

ou:

```
function User($name,$pass){
    $this->username = $name;
    $this->password = $pass; //Não tem problema armazenar assim.
}
```

Se eu utilizar a encriptação, meu sistema ficará muito lento com muitos usuários logando ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Obrigado pela aceitação, mas [não precisa aceitar uma resposta tão rápido](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/494/devemos-ter-pressa-ao-aceitar-respostas)! Isso pode reduzir as chances de que apareça uma melhor.

Comment: Quando li sua pergunta, entendi que você estaria construindo um sistema extremamente simples, com apenas um usuário, uma senha, e sem base de dados. É isso mesmo? Se não for, as outras respostas são muito mais adequadas que a minha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu fiz uma [pergunta relacionada (em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689257/should-hardcoded-passwords-be-salted-hashed) sobre como tratar senhas engessadas no código. A resposta que obtive é que é sim recomendável utilizar algum tipo de *hash* (com *salt*) nessas senhas.

O raciocínio por trás disso é o seguinte: alguém pode obter acesso ao seu código-fonte, e nesse caso a senha não seria exposta, somente o hash. E o [conselho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10689599/825789) que me deram foi guardar o hash da senha em um arquivo separado, de maneira que o código-fonte não precise ser alterado em múltiplas instalações da aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

O public e private da orientação a objetos tem a ver com a organização e modularização do seu código e *não* são um fator importaque nte no quesito segurança. Uma variável pública não vai ser visível fora do seu programa e uma variável privada fazendo idiotice ainda vai ser um problema de segurança.

Quanto ao hashing, não use md5! O md5 é um hash que foi feito pra ser muito rápido de executar e isso é uma coisa ruim quando você está lidando com senhas. Se um hacker conseguir acesso a uma cópia do seu banco de dados com os hashs das senhas, ele vai poder "chutar" as senhas dos seus usuários muito mais rápido que que ele poderia fazer via a interface web normal. Quanto mais rápido for a sua função de hash, mais senhas o hacker consegue chutar por minuto e menos tempo vai levar para ele descobrir a senha de verdade.

Para armazenar senhas, o melhor é usar um hash lerdo, de preferência um em que você possa passar configurar a lentidão com um parâmetro para deixar o hash o mais lerdo possível sem afetar negativamente a sua performance. Alguns exemplos comuns desses hashs especiais para senhas são o bcrypt, o PBKDF2 e o scrypt. Também recomendo fortemente usar alguma biblioteca pronta que implemente esses protocolos de senha, já que é muito fácil implementar algo inseguro se você fizer na mão. No caso do PHP (p a partir da versão 5.5), você pode usar as funções `password_hash` e `password_verify`, que implementam um protocolo de senha usando o bcrypt.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: O motivo pelo qual o MD5 é ruim não é esse. O MD5 de fato foi criado e projetado com a intenção de ser seguro. O problema é descobriram-se várias vulnerabilidades no algoritmo do MD5, até por fim ele ser definitivamente quebrado.

Comment: Quanto a esse negócio de "hash lerdo" isso não é verdade. Se o seu hash é seguro e o espaço de possíveis resultados é grande demais para uma busca exaustiva, então não há porque impor lerdeza. E outra, eu poderia implementar um hash bem lerdo da seguinte forma: Utilize a encriptação mais tosca e fácil de ser violada que tiver e coloca um sleep de alguns dias: Pronto, eu tenho um hash lerdo, mas absolutamente idiota.

Comment: @Victor: O treco do hash lerdo se chama [Key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching). A idéia é se proteger do caso em que o hacker tem uma cópia do seu BD com as senhas hasheadas. Nesse caso, o hacker vai tentar adivinhas as senhas na força bruta, chutando uma de cada vez e testando se o hash bate com o hash do BD. Nesse caso, o tamanho da saida do hash não importa (o espaço de busca do hacker são as senhas plaintext em potencial, como "senha01" ou "qwerty) e você fazer um sleep não adianta pq o hacker não vai fazer essas pausas.

Comment: @Victor: E o md5 não está quebrado (ainda) do ponto de vista de senhas. O problema do md5 é que acharam uma forma de você poder construir duas mensagens que dão no mesmo hash. No entanto, vc não tem controle sobre o hash resultante nisso, vc só sabe que vai ser o mesmo. No caso da senha, isso não é suficiente já que o desafio é achar uma mensagem que dê em um hash específico. Para detalhes veja http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23116/md5-collision-attacks-are-they-relevant-in-password-hashing

Comment: Ok, mas então por favor dê uma revisada no texto porque ele me levou a entender outra coisa. Acho que dá para você se expressar melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Num sistema de login, as passwords devem ser persistidas (numa base de dados, por exemplo) depois de terem sido *hashadas* (pela falta de melhor palavra) com um *salt* gerado aleatoriamente para esse utilizador (como referido pelo @bfavaretto). Assim, na BD, cada utilizador deve ter pelo menos 3 itens guardados: `username`, `hashed password` e o `salt`.

Assim que a password do user entra no servidor, deve-se seguir estes passos (em pseudocódigo):

```
login(username, password) {
    //obter informacao do user
    User user = bd.getUser(username);

    //obter o salt deste user
    string salt = user.salt;

    //"hashar" a password introduzida pelo utilizador
    //e verificar se corresponde a' password na BD
    if(Hash(password, salt) == user.hashed_password) {
        //login com sucesso
    }
}
```

Não te esqueças de que, quando um utilizador novo se regista, é necessário gerar o *salt* aleatório:

```
registar_user(username, password) {

    string salt = random(); //gerar salt
    string hashed_password = Hash(password, salt); //"hashar" password com o salt gerado

    db.Insert(username, hashed_password, salt);
}
```

**Nota**: Atenção, não confundir *hashing* com encriptação. MD5 e' uma algoritmo de hash, não de encriptação. Alem disso, [já foi provado em 1995 e em 2004](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) que o algoritmo MD5 tem falhas graves e **não deve ser usado**. Em vez disso, usa SHA256 ou SHA512.

Algoritmos de encriptação são usados noutras situações, para impedir que mensagens interceptadas possam ser decifradas ou alteradas, por exemplo. Existem algoritmos simétricos (AES) ou assimétricos (RSA).

> Se eu utilizar a encriptação, meu sistema ficará muito lento com muitos usuários logando ao mesmo tempo?

Algoritmos de hashing são muito rápidos, especialmente quando o input é pequeno, como no caso das passwords. Além disso, a segurança vem sempre antes da performance. A performance pode ser melhorada depois, escalando verticalmente ou horizontalmente.

Comment: Desculpa @bigown, submiti uma edicao logo a seguir a' tua :x as alteracoes foram apagadas! Ainda assim, obrigado pelo edit!

Comment: O método que você sugere é mesmo o correto, mas entendi que a pergunta seria sobre casos mais simples, onde não se pode/que usar uma base de dados. Ou entendi errado?

Comment: * "que" acima = "quer".

Comment: Realmente o autor não mencionou bases de dados.. Eu assumi que algum sistema de persistência de dados vai ser usado.. Uma aplicação não pode manter a informação de todos os utilizadores em memória permanentemente...

Answer (score 0):

Como você processa as senhas no seu código é irrelevante. O que importa é como armazena por exemplo no banco de dados.

No seu código você não está armazenando no banco de dados, mas sim apenas numa variável de classe. Portanto não faz sentido usar qualquer função de hash ou criptografia, pois isso não vai agregar nenhuma segurança ao seu script.

O que você tem de se preocupar com hashes é apenas quando for armazenar no banco de dados.